# Recursive search of node in tree

Tags: recursion, rust

I want to build a tree using exactly two structs: `Node` and `Tree` and then recursively search for a target node from the tree. If a target is found, return `true`, else return `false`.

The challenge for me here is how to recursively call the `find` function, since it is only defined on `Tree` not `Node`.

```
pub struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

pub struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    /// Creates an empty tree
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Tree { root: None }
    }

    // search the tree
    pub fn find(&self, key: &T) -> bool {
        let root_node = &self.root; // root is Option

        match *root_node {
            Some(ref node) => {

                if node.value == *key {
                    return true;
                }

                let target_node = if *key < node.value {
                    &node.left
                } else {
                    &node.right
                };

                match *target_node {
                    Some(sub_node) => sub_node.find(key),
                    None => {
                        return false;
                    } 
                }
            }
            None => return false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mytree: Tree<i32> = Tree::new();

    let node1 = Node {
        value: 100,
        left: None,
        right: None,
    };
    let boxed_node1 = Some(Box::new(node1));

    let root = Node {
        value: 200,
        left: boxed_node1,
        right: None,
    };
    let boxed_root = Some(Box::new(root));
    let mytree = Tree { root: boxed_root };

    let res = mytree.find(&100);
}
```

The current code reports the error:

```
error: no method named `find` found for type `Box<Node<T>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:36:48
   |
36 |                     Some(sub_node) => sub_node.find(key),
   |                                                ^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `find` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `Node<T> : std::iter::Iterator`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following traits define an item `find`, perhaps you need to implement one of them:
   = help: candidate #1: `std::iter::Iterator`
   = help: candidate #2: `core::str::StrExt`
```

I understand that `find` is only implemented on `Tree`, so there is an error, but I don't think it is efficient to implement `find` on both `Tree` and `Node`. Any hint to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the majority of the implementation to the `Node` type, then leave only a small shim in `Tree`:

```
impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    pub fn find(&self, key: &T) -> bool {
        self.root.as_ref().map(|n| n.find(key)).unwrap_or(false)
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> Node<T> {
    // search the tree
    pub fn find(&self, key: &T) -> bool {
        if self.value == *key {
            return true;
        }

        let target_node = if *key < self.value {
            &self.left
        } else {
            &self.right
        };

        target_node.as_ref().map(|n| n.find(key)).unwrap_or(false)
    }
}
```

However, I might avoid multiple comparisons by just matching on the result:

```
pub fn find(&self, key: &T) -> bool {
    use ::std::cmp::Ordering::*;

    match self.value.cmp(key) {
        Equal => true,
        Less => self.left.as_ref().map(|n| n.find(key)).unwrap_or(false),
        Greater => self.right.as_ref().map(|n| n.find(key)).unwrap_or(false),
    }
}
```

Or

```
pub fn find(&self, key: &T) -> bool {
    use ::std::cmp::Ordering::*;

    let child = match self.value.cmp(key) {
        Equal => return true,
        Less => self.left.as_ref(),
        Greater => self.right.as_ref(),
    };

    child.map(|n| n.find(key)).unwrap_or(false)
}
```

> I found it is hard to understand `target_node.as_ref().map(|n| n.find(key)).unwrap_or(false)`. I just started to learn the iterator. Is that possible to explain the long expression step by step?

Just follow the type signatures of each function:

1. `self` is a `&Node<T>`
2. `&self.left` / `&self.right` / `target_node` are a `&Option<Box<Node<T>>>`
3. [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) converts an `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`. Now we have `Option<&Box<Node<T>>>`.
4. [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) applies a function (which may change the contained type) to the option if it is `Some`, otherwise it leaves it `None`.

   1. The function we apply is `Node::find`, which takes a `&Node<T>` and returns a `bool`.
   2. `Box<T>` implements `Deref` so any methods on `T` appear on `Box<T>`.
   3. [Automatic dereferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423) allows us to treat `&Box<T>` as `Box<T>`.
   4. Now we have `Option<bool>`
5. [`Option::unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) returns the contained value if there is one, otherwise the fallback value provided. The final type is `bool`.

There is no usage of the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait. Both `Iterator` and `Option` have a `map` method. If you are interested in the fact that they have the same name and do similar things, that [is what people refer to as a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). Understanding monads is interesting but not *required* to actually use them.

Comment: For example, target_node.as_ref() convert a reference (&Tree) to ?? (&T)

Comment: I deleted my first comment question since I felt bad about asking too many...   Didn't expect you still see it and answer everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Implement the `find` method on `Node` and create a stub `find` method for `Tree` which could look like this:

```
impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    pub fn find(&self, key: &T) -> bool {
        match self.root.as_ref() {
            None => false,
            Some(x) => x.find(key)
        }
    }
}
```